# Highlighting A String Based on given indices

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I'm given

```
const s = "Old Man's War"
//Each indices represent the beginning and end index of the string
const indices = [
     [ 0, 0 ],
     [ 5, 5],
     [ 11, 11]
]
```

The indices represent beginning and end of what I want to highlight.
So I want to return something like

```
<span class="bold">O</span>ld M
<span class="bold">a</span>n's W
<span class="bold">a</span>r
```

How can I do this? Can't seem to come up with a decent algorithm.

Comment: I feel like the answer to this is to collapse your array into a capture/replace regex

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option is to `.split()` the string into an array, prepend `<span class="bold">` to each start index, append `</span>` to each end index, and `.join()` it back together:

```js
const s = "Old Man's War"
const indices = [[0,0],[5,5],[11,11]]

let result = indices.reduce((str, [start,end]) => {
  str[start] = `<span class="bold">${str[start]}`;
  str[end] = `${str[end]}</span>`;
  return str;
}, s.split("")).join("");

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
```

```css
.bold { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: What a clever solution. I had problems of keeping the subset after modifying the string once, because once modified, the subset indexes change. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

- Get first the slice of strings based on indices
- Loop over string if the current index matches `0th` index first value then add the sliced string from the `map` to final string and increase the index by second value of indices 0th element(end index)
- else normally append it to final string

```js
const s = "Old Man's War"
const indices = [[0,0],[2,4],[5,5],[11,11]]

const final = indices.map(([start,end])=> s.slice(start,end+1))

let output = ''

for(let i=0; i<s.length; i++){
  if(indices[0][0] === i){
    output += `<span class="bold">${final[0]}</span>`
    i += indices[0][1]
    indices.shift()
    final.shift()
  } else{
    output += s[i]
  }
}

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output;
```

```css
.bold { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```